# Replacing elements inside a dictionary Python given a list of current items

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary which looks like the following one. What I am trying to do is to find what months are missing and add them as a new key with a value of Nan.

```
{'Congress': {'April': '5.902',
  'August': '5.925',
  'January': '5.881',
  'February': '5.888',
  'July': '5.920',
  'June': '5.910',
  'March': '5.896',
  'May': '5.906',
  'November': '5.942',
  'October': '5.938',
  'September': '5.933'},
 'Entity': {'April': '64.320',
  'August': '64.642',
  'December': '64.825',
  'January': '63.965',
  'February': '64.089',
  'July': '64.604',
  'June': '64.509',
  'March': '64.221',
  'May': '64.404',
  'October': '64.757',
  'September': '64.690'}}
```

In the congress dictionary we are missing December and in the Entity dictionary we are missing November.

What I've tried so far is to create a list called months and iterate over it to find which values of the dictionary are not in the list. However this does not seem to work because when I try to print it, it does not print anything so it won't add the key and value for sure.

```
list_of_months =['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']

for k, v in newd.items():
  for x in v.keys():
    if x not in list_of_months :
      print(x)
```

Expected output should be:

```
{'Congress': {'April': '5.902',
  'December': 'Nan' ---------------------> Missing value to be added
  'August': '5.925',
  'January': '5.881',
  'February': '5.888',
  'July': '5.920',
  'June': '5.910',
  'March': '5.896',
  'May': '5.906',
  'November': '5.942',
  'October': '5.938',
  'September': '5.933'},
 'Entity': {'April': '64.320',
  'November': 'Nan' ---------------------> Missing value to be added
  'August': '64.642',
  'December': '64.825',
  'January': '63.965',
  'February': '64.089',
  'July': '64.604',
  'June': '64.509',
  'March': '64.221',
  'May': '64.404',
  'October': '64.757',
  'September': '64.690'}}
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong and what would be a better way of checking current months and adding those that are missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set` difference to check for missing month

**Ex:**

```
list_of_months ={'January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'}

for k,v in data.items():
    for i in list_of_months - set(v.keys()): # Check for missing Month
        v[i] = 'Nan'      # Add Month
            
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Congress': {'April': '5.902',
              'August': '5.925',
              'December': 'Nan',
              'February': '5.888',
              'January': '5.881',
              'July': '5.920',
              'June': '5.910',
              'March': '5.896',
              'May': '5.906',
              'November': '5.942',
              'October': '5.938',
              'September': '5.933'},
 'Entity': {'April': '64.320',
            'August': '64.642',
            'December': '64.825',
            'February': '64.089',
            'January': '63.965',
            'July': '64.604',
            'June': '64.509',
            'March': '64.221',
            'May': '64.404',
            'November': 'Nan',
            'October': '64.757',
            'September': '64.690'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go... You may need to modify it a little bit for exactly using it for your use case.

**Code:**

```py
dt = {'Congress': {'April': '5.902',
                   'August': '5.925',
                   'January': '5.881',
                   'February': '5.888',
                   'July': '5.920',
                   'June': '5.910',
                   'March': '5.896',
                   'May': '5.906',
                   'November': '5.942',
                   'October': '5.938',
                   'September': '5.933'},
      'Entity': {'April': '64.320',
                 'August': '64.642',
                 'December': '64.825',
                 'January': '63.965',
                 'February': '64.089',
                 'July': '64.604',
                 'June': '64.509',
                 'March': '64.221',
                 'May': '64.404',
                 'October': '64.757',
                 'September': '64.690'}
                 }

months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
          "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}


def fill_months(dictionary: dict, replace: str = "NaN") -> dict:
  """
  Fill missing months with some replacement string (default: NaN).
  
  Args:
    dictionary: Dictionary which has the missing months.
    replace: Values to be added for the missing months.

  Returns:
    Dictionary with missing month and some string value.  
  """
  for idx in (months - set(dictionary.keys())):
    dictionary[idx] = replace
  return dictionary


print(fill_months(dt["Congress"]))
print(fill_months(dt["Entity"]))
```